# Can I return call to a jsp that is another package in struts-config file of struts2

Tags: struts2

I have 2 packages in struts-config file one for login and online for the rest of the pages, once I have processed the login credentials I want to forward the result to a jsp in the online package. How do I do this?

```
<result type="redirect" name="overview">overview</result>
```

I cant simply use overview as overview is in online package and this result type is defined in the login package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [results docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/redirect-action-result.html) on the Struts 2 wiki.

First, you need to use the "redirectAction" result type since you're redirecting to an action. Second, you need to use the "namespace" attribute to explicitly define the result's namespace, or it will default to the current one.

Comment: Could you give me an example for the same.. or a link too would be useful. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @zDroid That is a link, with an example.